# Log File Comparison in Python

Tags: python, software-testing, unit-tests

Are there any tools/modules/libraries in python that allow for file comparison? It should allow for regular expressions that can ignore items that shouldn't be compared such as log timestamps, file/line number, etc. but still compare the log level and message part of the log. It will provide for comparing canonical log lines in unit testing.

I have found some related posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512016/how-to-compare-two-files-as-part-of-unittest-while-getting-useful-output-in-cas) but they use unittest framework and also only work on line by line comparisons which doesn't meet my intended use case.

**Note**: Canonical implies official, so these lines it will be comparing shouldn't change from implementation to implementation. A change in canonical logs indicates a change in behavior. Here is an [article](https://stripe.com/blog/canonical-log-lines) on canonical logs.

Comment: If it's solely for unit testing, I would, instead of comparing log files, mock the logger and assert on the calls they receive.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but its not only for unit testing. The idea is using canonical statements that apply to live use as well as testing. These statements attempt to capture behavior and are agnostic of the implementation details.